# Having issues with accessing pre-recorded video in Android Studio - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I am trying to build a feature in an app where upon clicking a button, it is supposed to access a pre-recorded video of thumb and calculate the heart rate. I have saved the video file in res/raw path as mp4 format. Now when I try to access the video with the Uri, it shows No path found. I need help with accessing the video file's path.

```
        heartRateButton.setOnClickListener {
        val videoResource = R.raw.heartratevideo
        val videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://${packageName}/${videoResource}")

        Log.e("VideoUri", "Video file uri is $videoUri") // This line outputs - android.resource://com.guardianangel.myguardian/2131689473


        val videoPath = UriUtils.convertMediaUriToPath(this,videoUri)
        Log.e("VideoPath", "Video file path is $videoPath") // null


        // Check if the videoPath is not null
        if (videoPath != null) {
            // Execute the AsyncTask to calculate heart rate
            val slowTask = SlowTask { heartRate ->
                // Display the heart rate as a toast message
                showToast(heartRate)
            }
            slowTask.execute(videoPath)
        } else {
            // Handle the case where videoPath is null
            Log.e("VideoPath", "Video file path is null")
        }
```

Here is the convertMediaUriToPath function:

```
    fun convertMediaUriToPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    val proj = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
    val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, proj, null, null, null)
    cursor?.use {
        if (it.moveToFirst()) {
            val column_index = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            return it.getString(column_index)
        }
    }
    return null // Return null if there's no valid path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "file path". That raw resource is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the Android device or emulator.

And, FWIW, `convertMediaUriToPath()` will fail for most `Uri` values on most Android devices. I recommend deleting that function.

Comment: How do I access the video then? Any help will be very helpful

Comment: @SarfrazNawaz What exactly are you looking to do with it? `MediaPlayer` and ExoPlayer should be able to work with a raw resource.

Comment: So I have a function which takes in a video path and processes the video to find the heart rate. I am trying to send the video path to the function. Now, I have manually saved the video inside /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.guardianangel.myguardian/files/Movies/heartratevideo.mp4 and trying to access it but it still says no path found

Comment: I am hard coding the path like this:

val videoFile = File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.guardianangel.myguardian/files/Movies/heartratevideo.mp4")

And sending this videoFile to the function to calculate the heart rate

Comment: @SarfrazNawaz: A raw resource is packaged into your app and cannot be changed, except by shipping a new app. You should calculate the heart rate on your own machine and simply package the calculated result along with the resource, rather than forcing every user to waste CPU/battery re-calculating a constant. Beyond that, we cannot help you debug this function without seeing it. In general, though, hard-coding paths does not work. Use `getFilesDir()` on `Context` to determine at runtime the proper value to use instead of `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.guardianangel.myguardian/files`.